# Login to Database in CrystalReports

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, crystal-reports

I have created Reports using CrystalReports adding four Access Database Connections.

My requirement is, **It should never prompt for UserID and Password After I install It on Client's Computer.**

I have also used parameters in Reports.

I know about how to pass login credentails design time but not sure If It will prompt again after Installation at Client PC.

I also Tried

> CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo

and went succeed, but failed when tried with report from multiple databases.

Comment: Check the following links.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112997/why-does-crystal-report-viewer-always-asks-for-login-details-to-access-database
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459966/crystal-report-always-asks-for-database-login

Comment: Thanks David Sir, But I already know about how to pass login information. I want to know is how to perform the same in the case of multiple databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the credentials for multiple databases, use the following code

```
    Dim Report1 As New CrystalReport1
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To Report1.DataSourceConnections.Count - 1
        Dim AccessDBFileName As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(Report1.DataSourceConnections.Item(i).ServerName)
        Dim Password As String = ""

        Select Case AccessDBFileName
            Case "Database1.mdb"
                Password = "Password1"
            Case "Database2.mdb"
                Password = "Password2"
            Case "Database3.mdb"
                Password = "Password3"
            Case "Database4.mdb"
                Password = "Password4"
        End Select

        Report1.DataSourceConnections.Item(i).SetLogon("", Password)
    Next
```

The GetFileName function retrieves the database file name from the path of the Access file.